# How to apply CSS locally on any online page?

Tags: html, css

For testing

I don't want to upload CSS to FTP on each change until the site is complete, but the site and content is online. (I'm not talking about saving page locally then apply CSS)

Can I just apply the CSS locally to any online page?

It would be easier to edit and see changes locally until the CSS work is done.

I want to see the applied effect on Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the closet way

http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:_7_eRIBRrhoJ:www.nealgrosskopf.com/tech/thread.php%3Fpid%3D60+http://www.nealgrosskopf.com/tech/thread.php%3Fpid%3D60&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in&client=firefox-a

but only for firefox

**Edit : 29 April 2010**

I found another better way

http://www.tomjewett.com/accessibility/508-eval-tools.html

> In FireFox, from the Web Developer toolbar, select CSS -> Add User Style
>   Sheet, browse to wherever you stored
>   it and click the Open button. When you
>   are finished, just un-check the "Add
>   User Style Sheet" on the toolbar CSS
>   menu.
>
> In Microsoft Internet Explorer, select Tools -> Internet Options... ->
>   Accessibility... and check the "Format
>   documents using my style sheets" box.
>   Using the Browse button, open the
>   lowvis.css style sheet from wherever
>   you stored it, and click OK to both
>   the Accessibility and the Internet
>   Options panels. When you are finished,
>   simply un-check the "...my style
>   sheets" box on the Accessibility
>   panel.

Comment: +1 Great find! For a cross-browser solution you will need something else, though. Even if you find something similar in IE8, it won't work in IE7, IE6, Safari, Opera.... Better go with one of the outlined suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: this is related to my question

Answer (score 1):

If the site you are testing for is not facing the public so speed doesn't matter, you could set up a service like [**dynDNS**](http://www.dyndns.com/) and turn your work PC into a web server. (Caveat: It's lots of work and you *need* to secure it.) You could then have all your style sheets on your local computer, and have your on-line site reference them like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jitendra.dyndns.org/styles/styles.css">
```

Comment: is there any option in IE and FF to achieve this

Comment: @Jitendra No, this has nothing to do with browsers. You would also need to set up a local hosting environment (if you don't already have one.), so this is a solution with a fair amount of work.

Comment: Firebug is different thing I know but my question is different

Comment: @jitendra what speaks against directly uploading the CSS whenever a change occurs? Is this too bothersome in your working environment?

Comment: yes because i can't access CSS from FTP but i can add css from CMS's UI and CMS ui doesn't have Syntax highlighting.It's a very unusual situation for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a proxy such as [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and use its URL remapping features to divert requests for the stylesheets to local files.

Comment: Great idea, but he would probably have to have a local web server running in order to serve the CSS - if you rewrite the URLs to `file:///` ones, the browser might give trouble because of security restrictions. Then again, it might not, it being only CSS.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. That's why I said "local files" and not "a local web server" (you **can** rewrite to a different HTTP URL if  you like, but local files are fine). 

And browsers won't give you security issues, the browser asks for http://example.com/foo.css and the proxy gives it a local file instead. The browser doesn't know the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use version control. Try http://git-scm.com/ or http://subversion.tigris.org/ ( http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ for a non-command line version)--it does a lot more, but it would allow you to do what you want, and what else it does it sounds like you might need.

Talk to your server admin about setting one or another up.

Comment: I'm for using version control any day, but how would it help the OP's situation?

Comment: He wants to 1) save his changes on a local machine and 2) have them affect an online site *without* uploading his changes. Editing your hosts file and using version control can get you this without any real disconnect, so long as you keep in mind what you're seeing isn't live until you commit your changes.

Comment: (I dunno, I assumed fiddling with your hosts file to have a common place to preview the result was standard stuff. Bad assumption on my part. It's just how I've used it.)

Comment: @DN I see. This is an interesting idea, as it bypasses the installing of a web server. But you're probably not going to be able to convert `/styles/styles.css` to a local repository request using a simple hosts file, not without some URL rewriting - for which, again, you would need a fully equipped web server installed.

Comment: I bow to your greater knowledge. I do what the sys admins tell me, and smile and nod and complain if they lock me out, is all.

Answer (score 1):

If you have web developer toolbar then you can view the current css and edit the same and then can see the changes ....

Its available for both firfox and IE

[Ie web developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) for IE

and [Firefox web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=web+developer&cat=all&advancedsearch=1&as=1&appid=1&lver=3.0&atype=0&pp=20&pid=5&sort=&lup=https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/downloads/latest/60/addon-60-latest.xpi?src=search) for firrefox